# Stop UIWebView Tap Gesture while its scrolling ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I am using tap gesture to detect tap on `UIWebView` and it works correct with following code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *targetGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
targetGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
targetGesture.delegate = self;
[_webView1 addGestureRecognizer:targetGesture];
```

And i am handling it with `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods as follows:-

```
(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender


(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer


(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

Now I want to disable tap gesture while `UIWebView` is scrolling.

Same as "NYTimes" ios app doing.

Comment: So what have you tried so far..?

Comment: Have tried to change tap from single to double.nothing worked. :(

Comment: What's the problem when you scoll UIWebView? Why you want to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tap gesture like this.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
tapGesture.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it by using following method of UIWebView:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        NSString *URL = [[request URL] absoluteString];
        DetailViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];
        controller.urlString = URL;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [webView stopLoading];
    }

    return YES;
}
```